# Invalid declarator before with map of struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to map a mapping between `string`s and a custom struct, `callable`. However, it's giving me "invalid declarator". I've tried a bunch of things, like `typedef`ing it (e.g. `typdef struct _c { } callable;`) but that just raises more errors.

I'm compiling with ideone.com, since I don't have a compiler at school but I still want to at least bang out decent code.

A minimum example ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/zl7dn6)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct callable {
  virtual void operator()(vector<string> args) = 0;
}

std::map<std::string, callable> commands =
{
  { "cmd", struct : callable
    {
      operator()(vector<string> args) {
        out << "cmd called with args:" << endl;
        for (auto i = args.begin(); args.end() != i; ++i) out << *i << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<string> args = {"hello", "world"};
  commands["cd"](args);
}
```

And the error is:

```
prog.cpp:11:33: error: invalid declarator before 'commands'
 std::map<std::string, callable> commands =
                                 ^
```

The expected output:

```
cmd called with args:
hello
world
```

---

As a side note, please provide an answer to this question before answering the more general question of mapping strings to code, unless this approach can't work.

Comment: Objects in a map are copied and thus truncated, which means your very approach can't work. Use `std::function` for this. Anyhow, if you had reduced your code to a minimal example, you wouldn't be asking about this error here.

Comment: @close voter: I provided an M"W"E, expected output, the current output, and a description of the problem I'm trying to solve. Note that I don't know enough to do this another way which is theoretically shorter -- this is the shortest I could make.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Er, what? Are you assuming that I know enough about C++ to shorten this further? Because I don't. Hence asking here. As far as I know, this is the minimum example for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: C++ is nor Java. )))

Comment: You really think the `return 0;` in `main()` is necessary, for example? It isn't, so this isn't minimal.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I feel, you are neatpicking and urge you to stop.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt ***I. Don't. Know.*** If I knew C++ better, I wouldn't be asking this question, because I'd already know the answer. I'm asking this question in hopes of learning the language more, and because that one weird thing that's causing this bug could easily make other people confused, and AFAIK it's not here yet.

Comment: I'm not nitpicking, but I'm indeed intentionally not doing the work of the one asking the question. There's a bunch that could just be stripped without changing the actual issue. The guideline requires that you strip this down as far as possible for good reasons.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, your code is broken on many levels. Sorry, but you need to study core language features. Read a book.

Comment: @SergeyA Know any good ones that your professor won't yell at you for having out in class when you're supposed to be working on their project? (And yeah, I have, but I'm bad at learning from books. Hence making a project and working through the errors.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax issues aside, your code smells Java. In C++ where functions are first-class citizens, you do not need to create callback classess for every possible callback. Instead, you simply pass function-like objects - either a pointer to function, or something wrapped inside `std::function`. The former is simpler, the latter is more powerful. I suggest to work with simple pointers first. For instance, your code might be looking like following:

```
void do_cmd(const std::vector<std::string>& args);
typedef void (*cmd_func)(const std::vector<std::string>& cmd_args);
std::map<std::string, cmd_func> cmd_map = { {"cmd", &do_cmd} };

int main() {
   (*cmd_map["cmd"])(args);
}
```

Comment: Just one small improvement: Use `typedef void func_type(vector<string> const& args);`, i.e. don't use the (unreadable) type alias for the pointer type but rather for the function type. Then, a `map<string, func_type*>` is clearly a map of function pointers.

Comment: Functions are not first-class citizens in C++, though. I'd reserve that qualifications to more functional languages, such as Haskell or Lisp.

Comment: OP's use of classes may indicate he wants a stateful command somewhere in his code. In that case, might a mention of functor objects and lambda expressions be useful?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I find it to be the matter of personal preferences. Both approaches are viable in my view.

Comment: @MicroVirus, from Wikipedia: `...programming language is said to have ... functions ... as first-class citizens ... This means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures.`  All of which is possible in C/C++ with function pointers.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, I personally suppose at this level OP is better of without lambdas :)))

Comment: Well OK, with C++11 I guess you could say that functions are becoming more first-class.

Comment: Hm, I see. So I have to define a function for every command I want to map?

Comment: @jaggedSpire I think my use of classes/structs indicates more that I'm not used to C++ thinking than that I have any particular purpose in mind.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - wasn't it the whole reason for the exercise?

Comment: @SergeyA Like I said, the purpose of the exercise is to give me a goal to work towards when learning C++, without having to work through the language-agnostic challenges in the program. Part of that is getting into a mindset that fits C++ more than the one I have, which has been fiddling with Rails too long to be useful to anyone.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, if you decide to learn brikmanship, would you start by simply laying bricks on top of each other, using your own invention as a clue and see how tall you can build and how spectacular the fall will be? Or you'd read something about it first? Better yet, should aspiring dentist start by drilling teeth of their patients with anything they find remotely usable? Or you prefer them to study first?

Comment: @SergeyA, no, because a wall can't be torn down as easily as code can be rewritten, and teeth are damaged far more permanently than code. If I mess up code, I can figure out how, why, and redo it better by deleting, then typing a bunch.

Comment: The problem is that you will (undoubtfully!) end up with the code which you believe is working - but the code will actually be broken. It would be unsupportable, terribly performant or will simply contain undefined behavior which would not see in a small program. Do not do this.

Answer (score 12):

You forgot the extra semicolon after struct:

```
struct callable {
  virtual void operator()(vector<string> args) = 0;
}; // <--- ; is needed.
```

This is what gives you the compiler error.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Unfortunately, this still ends up causing more errors, which are what I thought I was getting before... this is confusing.

Comment: This was my problem too. Why, oh why, does `g++` sometimes give a cryptic, wild-goose-chasing error instead of its usual "missing semicolon after struct declaration". (Perhaps the answer is the sheer complexity of C++'s syntax.)

Answer (score 2):

`callable` is an abstract base class and can't be instantiated. Thus, you can't store an instance of one in a `map`. You *can* store a pointer to a ABC in a map, but don't use a raw pointer use a smart one, such as below:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<callable> >
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just lack a ';' after the closing brace of the struct declaration...